# cin input (input is an int) when I input a letter, instead of printing back incorrect once, it prints correct once then inc for the rest of the loop

Tags: c++, cin, multiplication

I'm making a multiplication practice program. As my title says, if I enter a letter into the console instead of a number, it will run off saying correct on the first one, but incorrect on the rest. Even if you're not touching the keyboard, it'll still spit out incorrect.

```
ans = table * i;
                    std::cout << table << " * " << i << " =" << std::endl;
                    std::cin >> input;
                    if(input == ans)
                    {
                            std::cout << "Correct! " << ans << std::endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            std::cout << "Incorrect, the answer was " << ans << std::endl;
                            input = 0;
                            ans = 0;
                    }
            }
```

Hopefully that gives you a view of what's happening in the code. Here's the output.

```
Enter the table you'd like to learn.
5
Enter the amount of multiples
3
5 * 0 =
s
Correct! 0
5 * 1 =
Incorrect, the answer was 5
5 * 2 =
Incorrect, the answer was 10
5 * 3 =
Incorrect, the answer was 15
```

What could I do to fix this problem? Thanks for your *input*.

Comment: `ans`, `table`, `i`, and `input` are all `int`s, right?

Comment: Correct @TheObscureQuestion, they are all ints.

Comment: When a *matching failure* occurs, no further characters are read, and any characters input are left in the input buffer (`stdin`) **unread** just waiting to bite you again on the next iteration of your loop -- *unless you handle the failure correctly and account for any characters that remain unread*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to structure the various test, but when taking input with `cin` (or generally with any input function), you must account for any characters in the input buffer that remain unread. With `cin`, you have three conditions you must validate:

1. `.eof()` (`eofbit`) is set. Either the end of input was reached, or the user manually generated an `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze, but see: [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/));
2. `.bad()` (`badbit`) is set. An unrecoverable stream error occurred; and
3. `.fail()` (`failbit`) is set. A matching, or other recoverable, failure occurred. When the failure occurs *input stops and no further characters are extracted from the input buffer*.

(you can combine 1 & 2 into a single test as input is over at that point)

With `failbit`, you must do two things. (1) you must clear the stream error state by calling `cin.clear()`, and (2) you must handle any characters that remain unread in the input buffer. Generally this is handled by including `<limits>` and calling:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

(which will clear up to `INT_MAX` characters from the input buffer, stopping when the delimiter (`'\n'` here) is encountered)

A short example that loops until a valid *integer* is input by the user could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    int x = 0;

    while (1)       /* loop continually until valid input received */
    {
        cout << "\nenter an integer: ";
        if (! (cin >> x) ) {            /* check stream state */
            /* if eof() or bad() break read loop */
            if (cin.eof() || cin.bad()) {
                cerr << "(user canceled or unreconverable error)\n";
                return 1;
            }
            else if (cin.fail()) {      /* if failbit */
                cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
                cin.clear();            /* clear failbit */
                /* extract any characters that remain unread */
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        }
        else {  /* on succesful read of int */
                /* extract any characters that remain unread */
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            break;  /* then break read loop */
        }
    }

    cout << "integer: " << x << '\n';
}
```

(as mentioned at the beginning, you can structure the tests many different ways, as long as you cover all three conditions.)

Additionally, you can check the stream bit explicitly by calling `rdstate()` instead of testing with `.fail()`, etc..., e.g.

```
if (std::cin.rdstate() == std::ios_base::failbit)
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cin_validate_int

enter an integer: no
error: invalid input.

enter an integer: "an integer"
error: invalid input.

enter an integer: abc 123
error: invalid input.

enter an integer: 123
integer: 123
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `cin >> input` and it can't parse the input as a number, it [sets `cin`'s `failbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction), and when `failbit` is set it doesn't actually read any more data until you clear it.

You should check for errors by calling [`cin.good()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good), and try to clear them with [`cin.clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear), but you shouldn't try to clear some errors (like [EOF](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof)) and instead should quit on them.