# Why does while (true) skip cin when it received invalid input?

Tags: c++, while-loop

This while-loop does not wait for input from cin after receiving wrong input (non-integer). Does cin somehow stay in a false state?

```
while (true) {
    int x {0};
    cout << "> ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "= " << x << endl;
}
```

I would expect this while-loop to wait for input everytime around, but that no longer happens when it receives wrong input.

Comment: You will benefit from this answer [cin input (input is an int) when I input a letter...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402749/cin-input-input-is-an-int-when-i-input-a-letter-instead-of-printing-back-inco/50403158#50403158)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `cin` fails, it stays in an invalid state until it's cleared.

[clear()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) without arguments can be used to unset the failbit after unexpected input

> Sets the stream error state flags by assigning them the value of
>   state. By default, assigns std::ios_base::goodbit which has the effect
>   of clearing all error state flags.

As [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) points out, you also have to clear the buffer.

Your example would be like this:

```
while (true) {
  int x{0};
  cout << "> ";
  if (!cin) {
    // unset failbit
    cin.clear();
    // clear the buffer
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
  cin >> x;
  cout << "= " << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: That's not actually enough, since the offending non-integer input will stay in `cin`s buffer, which will cause `cin >> x` to fail immediately, and the loop to continue but still be stuck on that input.