# How the standard input output operation done in C++

Tags: c++, io

I have this code.

```
int main() {

int x;
cin>>x;
cout<<x<<endl;
char ch;
cin>>ch;
cout<<ch<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<x<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

if I give input R495 at first time then the output shows

0

0

Can anyone explain me why happened this. And why the console does not wait for me to enter other input.

Comment: You may benefit from [A: cin input (input is an int) when I input a letter, instead of printing back incorrect once,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402749/cin-input-input-is-an-int-when-i-input-a-letter-instead-of-printing-back-inco/50403158?r=SearchResults&s=1|35.2109#50403158)

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Why should it wait? This seems to be one of the biggest misunderstandings beginners have about I/O in C++. They expect `cin >>` statements to be synchronised with the enter key on the keyboard. But in C++ all I/O is abstract, it works the same whether you are reading from the keyboard, from a file, from a socket or a string, and there's no enter key on those things. The enter key affects when the system makes typed data available, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

After the wrong input, state of i/o stream is changed to a failed state.
Without clearing it, you will get the wrong input.
You can check if it is in a failed state with `cin.fail()`.

```
...
cin>>x;
cout<<x<<endl;
-----------------
if (cin.fail())
{
  cout<<"Failed state"<<endl;
}else{
  cout<<"Good state"<<endl;
}
...
```

More info here [std::ios::fail](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/)

Answer (score -1):

```
int x;
cin>>x;
```

This is the first part. Here you said, that user will input x, but x will be Integer. Integer is whole number. So you need to enter a number.

```
char ch;
cin>>ch;
```

Here you said that user will input ch, but type of ch is Character. This means that you need to enter character for this to work (you can also enter integer here, which then will be mapped to ASCII value etc).