# What if user inputs float in integer variable?

Tags: c++, exception

```cpp
int number, number2, number3;

cout << "Enter a number: ";
while(!(cin >> number))
{
    cout << "Wrong input! Enter a number: " << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
}
cout << "Enter number2 and number3: ";
cin >> number2;
cin >> number3;
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 2.345
Wrong Input! Enter a number:
Enter number2 and number3:
```

The program ignores the input of number2 and number3 when I enter float number.

How to handle this???

Comment: [cin input (input is an int) when I input a letter, instead of printing back incorrect once, …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402749/cin-input-input-is-an-int-when-i-input-a-letter-instead-of-printing-back-inco/50403158?r=SearchResults&s=1|34.4906#50403158) will help. Works the same for any numeric type.

Comment: use `float` instead of `int`

Comment: Note that the user enters **text**, which is not an `int` nor a `float`. It's a series of characters that can be interpreted in various ways. The question isn't about inputting a `float`, but about inputting text that does not represent a valid integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using (cin>>number) as a condition, it will only be false if you enter a non-digit character. So in your case even if you enter a float, it will be false and the value of number = 2 (incase you enter 2.45).

Now the issue that you are facing is solved as follows :

```
int main(){

        int number, number2, number3;

        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        while(!(cin >> number))
        {
            cout << "Wrong input! Enter a number: " << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
        }
        cout << "Enter number2 and number3: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
        cin >> number2; cin >> number3;
        return 0;
}
```

This may be because it still has the some value in the input stream as it is not cleared, and it will pick that for number2 and number3.If I am using the above code as it is without cin.clear() and cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n') after the while loop, I am getting number2=0 and number3=0 as follows :

```
Enter a number: 2.45
Enter number2 and number3: 
Value in number : 2
Value in number2 : 0
Value in number3 : 0
```

Not sure about it myself as well .Got the following output with this :

```
int main(){

        int number, number2, number3;
        string temp;
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        while(!(cin >> number))
        {
             cout << "Wrong input! Enter a number: " << endl;
             cin.clear();
             cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
        }
        std::getline(std::cin, temp);
        cout << "Enter number2 and number3: ";
        // cin.clear();
        // cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
        cin >> number2; cin >> number3;
        cout<<"Remaining in cin : "<<temp<<"\nValue in number : "<<number<<"\nValue in number2 : "<<number2<<"\nValue in number3 : "<<number3;
        return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Enter a number: 2.45
Enter number2 and number3: 2
3
Remaining in cin : .45
Value in number : 2
Value in number2 : 2
Value in number3 : 3
```

I hope someone could clear my doubt as well. Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much @aru_sha4, you have solved my problem. I am having a project on different types of expression solving including Horner's Method and at every stage I was facing that error which then becomes an issue. But thanks to you, you really has solved. That getline() method has solved the problem Hurrah!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int
main ()
{
  float x = 12.5, y = 13.3, z = 14.8; 
  cout << "value of x :" << int(x) << "\n"; 
  cout << " value of y :" << int(y) << "\n"; 
  cout << " value of z :" << int(z) << "\n"; 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why your code would solve the problem.