# When the input is a character or a word, it doesn't display "Invalid input"

Tags: c++, c++11

When the input is `>2` or `<0` it display "Invalid input.". But when the input is an alphabet or a word it does not display "Invalid input."

```
int main()
{
    int userInput, gesture;

    cout << "Rock(0), Paper(1), Scissor(2): ";
    cin >> userInput;

    srand(time(0));
    gesture = rand() % 3;

    if (isdigit(userInput) && userInput >= 0 || userInput <= 2)        //I think it's a logic error, but idk how to fix it.
    {
        switch (gesture)
        {
        case (0):
            if (userInput == gesture)
                cout << "The computer is rock. You are rock too. It is a draw." << endl;
            else if (userInput == 1 && gesture == 0)
                cout << "The computer is rock. You are paper. You win." << endl;
            else if (userInput == 2 && gesture == 0)
                cout << "The computer is rock. You are scissor. You lose." << endl;
            break;
       
        }
    }

    else  
        cout<<"Invalid input.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your isdigit(userInput) code is missing. Add that if you can.

Comment: replace `isdigit(userInput)` with `userinput < 3`. `isdigit` expects a `char`(even than formally its argumwnt is `int`). It's a long story why it's like this. `|| userInput <= 2` is unnecessary (it can fail on negative input).

Comment: You may find [cin input (input is an int)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50403158/3422102) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this:

```
if (isdigit(userInput) && userInput >= 0 || userInput <= 2)
```

The signature of `isdigit` is this:

```
int isdigit( int ch );
```

so one might be fooled into thinking that it expects an `int`, like 1 or 34. In reality, it expects an argument of type `unsigned char` converted into an `int`. Why, you'd ask? Because it was included into C++ via the standard library of the C language, and in C there's a special marker `EOF` that marks the "end of file" in a stream of characters (just like `\0` marks the end of a string). The problem is that EOF cannot be represented as a `char`, hence many C functions designed to handle strings accept `int`s.   The only thing we know about `EOF` is that it is negative.

So, the usual usage of `isdigit` is something like this:

```
unsigned char c = '0';
// ...
if (isdigit(c)) { /* ... */ }
```

What you should do, then?
Well, the simpler, the better

```
  if (userInput >= 0 && userInput <= 2)
```

If you want to check for completely invalid user input, check the state of `cin`

```
  if (std::cin && userInput >= 0 && userInput <= 2)
```

An alternative is to initialize `userInput` with a plain wrong value, e.g. with `-1`. If `cin` fails, you'll know something wrong has happened anyway, because `userInput` woul'd have an ivalid value `-1`.

Use `std::cin.clear()` to clear the "fail state" flag in  `std::cin` and unblock it.