# How do you write a program that tests if a user's inputs are integers and returns a message if they enter characters?

Tags: c++

The homework is that you need to write a program that takes 4 integers between 0-100 inclusive from the user, computes their average, and displays the four integers as well as the average on the output screen, like in the following format:

Your grades were: 70 80 60 90

Your average grade is 75

You also have to make sure that the program produces a mathematically correct result, which it may not because of integer division. You also have to make it that the user cannot enter numbers outside the range 0-100, and the user cannot enter characters or strings.

So far, I have met the first two restrictions, however I am having trouble setting up the code such that the user cannot enter any characters. Can someone take a look at the following code and see what I'm doing wrong? Note that this is only the part of the code that pertains to my issue.

```
int main()
{
    int grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4;
    float grade_average;
    char g1char;  

    cout << "Enter 4 integer grades (%): ";
    cin >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3 >> grade4;
    g1char = grade1;

    if (isdigit(g1char) == 0) {
    cout << "Incorrect input - characters not allowed; Please run the program again and enter proper values";
}
```

Comment: Side note: Instead of writing `isdigit(g1char) == 0`, it is simpler and more common to write `!isdigit(g1char)`.

Comment: There are numerous functions already available that can be used to determine if a character string is all digits.  `std::stoi`, `std::strtol`, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cin input (input is an int) when I input a letter, instead of printing back incorrect once, it prints correct once then inc for the rest of the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402749/cin-input-input-is-an-int-when-i-input-a-letter-instead-of-printing-back-inco)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) expects an `int` with the value of a character code. However, you are not passing it a character code. If you want to pass a character code, you must read the input as a string or as individual characters, not as a number. Otherwise, you will have no character codes to pass to `std::isdigit`.

However, unless the task description explicitly requires you to check that every single character is a digit, you don't have to call `std::isdigit`. This would also not be meaningful in some cases. For example, when the user enters negative numbers such as `-34`, the first character is not a digit. With this specific task, the user is not supposed to enter negative numbers, but the user may want to enter `+34` for the number `34`, which should also be valid (unless the task description explicitly states otherwise).

You have two options to solve this problem. You can either

1. rely on the stream extraction operator `>>` and check whether an error occurred using [`std::cin.fail`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail), or
2. read one line of input as a string using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to attempt to convert the string into to a number. The function [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) will tell you whether the input was valid or not, i.e. whether it was possible to convert the string to a number.

The first option may be easier to use, but the second option is generally recommended for line-based user input, as it will always read one line at a time.

However, both options do have one problem: They will accept input such as `6sdfh4q` as valid input for the number `6`. Therefore, if you want perfect input validation, you should also check the part of the input that was not converted to a number, to check whether it is acceptable. All whitespace characters are probably harmless, but all other characters are not, so I recommend that you use [`std::isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) for this purpose.