# How to ask the user to input the number in my code in order to print out the result

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, area, abstract-base-class

How can I ask the user to input those two numbers and print out the result in C++ here? Please, I need your help. I am new to C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b; }
    virtual int area ()
      { return 0; }
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    int area ()
      { return width * height; }
};

class Triangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    int area ()
      { return (width * height / 2); }
};

int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  Triangle trgl;
  Polygon * ppoly1 = &rect;
  Polygon * ppoly2 = &trgl;
  ppoly1->set_values (4,5);
  ppoly2->set_values (4,5);
  cout << ppoly1->area() << '\n';
  cout << ppoly2->area() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What book are you learning from?  Seems odd that it'd cover inheritance before `std::cin`.

Comment: Off-topic, but your `Polygon` class lacks a virtual destructor, thus is unsafe to be used polymorphically.

Comment: [cin input (input is an int)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50403158/3422102) may help.

Comment: I'd avoid using inheritance for a while if you're a beginner - unless your university requires it. Inheritance is easily overused.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read about constructors a little bit, you can use cin and cout here. Please find this code and see how I have done for rectangle.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b; }
    virtual int area ()
      { return 0; }
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
  private:
      int a, b;
  public:
      Rectangle(){
          cout<<"Please enter height and width: ";
          cin>>a>>b;
          set_values(a,b);
      }
    int area ()
      { return width * height; }
};

class Triangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    int area ()
      { return (width * height / 2); }
};

int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  Triangle trgl;
  Polygon * ppoly1 = &rect;
  Polygon * ppoly2 = &trgl;
  //ppoly1->set_values (4,5);
  ppoly2->set_values (4,5);
  cout << ppoly1->area() << '\n';
  cout << ppoly2->area() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is a matching failure handled in the code? What if the user slips and taps `'r'` instead of `'4'`?

Comment: The matching failure cases have not been handled here, as the person was only interested in knowing how to take inputs and display outputs. Although, in case if he enters any string value instead of integer, it will return 0 as output, cause when multiplying r*4 it will run into failure and return 0 value.

Comment: Sad to have to point this out in 2021, but *it will return 0 as output* is only guaranteed to be true if compiling to C++11 or a more recent Standard revision.

Comment: Thanks for informing me, I didn't had knowledge about it.