# items added to an array, but all display with details from the last one entered

Tags: c++

I just wrote this code today because my teacher told me to, and well... It's about doing a question of which color I want to of a book (only 3 options, red, green and blue), after that will make a registry of the books (asking the title, author and year of publication), 2 books if I selected red, 3 if I selected green, 4 if I selected blue.

The problem is that when shows the final result, the code ignores all input except the last one, and that input replicates itself, can anyone help me?

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
enum Color{
    rojo,verde,azul
};
struct libro{
    string bookNumber;
    Color color;
};
int main(){
    string t,au,a;
    int color, bookNumber;
    cout<<"Seleccione el color del libro, 0. Rojo, 1. Verde, 2. Azul: ";
    cin>>color;
    switch(color){
        case rojo:
            bookNumber = 2;
            break;
        case verde:
            bookNumber = 3;
            break;
        case azul:
            bookNumber = 4;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Opción incorrecta" << endl;
            break;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<bookNumber;i++) {
        cout <<"Introduce el titulo del libro " <<i+1<<": "<<endl;
        cin>>t;
        cout <<"Introduce el autor del libro "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
        cin>>au;
        cout <<"Introduce el anio del libro " <<i+1<<": "<<endl;
        cin>>a;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<bookNumber;i++){
        cout <<"\t"<<"Titulo: "<<t<<endl;
        cout <<"\t"<<"Autor: "<<au<<endl;
        cout <<"\t"<<"Anio: "<<a<<endl;
        switch(color){
            case rojo: 
                cout<<"\t"<<"Color: Rojo" <<endl; break;
            case verde:
                cout<<"\t"<<"Color: Verde" <<endl; break;
            case azul:
                cout<<"\t"<<"Color: Azul" <<endl; break;
        }
    }
}
```

And I will leave here an example of what gives when executing:

```
Seleccione el color del libro, 0. Rojo, 1. Verde, 2. Azul: 2
Introduce el titulo del libro 1: 
ABS
Introduce el autor del libro 1: 
ABS
Introduce el anio del libro 1: 
2003
Introduce el titulo del libro 2: 
BCA
Introduce el autor del libro 2: 
BCA
Introduce el anio del libro 2: 
2005
Introduce el titulo del libro 3: 
WWW
Introduce el autor del libro 3: 
WWW
Introduce el anio del libro 3: 
4444
Introduce el titulo del libro 4: 
PPP 
Introduce el autor del libro 4: 
PPP
Introduce el anio del libro 4: 
8788
        Titulo: PPP
        Autor: PPP
        Anio: 8788
        Color: Azul
        Titulo: PPP
        Autor: PPP
        Anio: 8788
        Color: Azul
        Titulo: PPP
        Autor: PPP
        Anio: 8788
        Color: Azul
        Titulo: PPP
        Autor: PPP
        Anio: 8788
        Color: Azul
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You overwrite your variables on each iteration of the first loop.  In the second loop you just output the same values multiple times.  Perhaps the intent of this lesson was to learn about arrays?

Comment: Looks like you need `std::vector<libro> books;`

Comment: And in your last `switch` the `break`s are missing.

Comment: You are tempting undefined behavior by failing to check the stream state after every input (especially numeric input where conversion is required). At minimum `if (!(cin>>color)) { std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n"; return 1; }`.  See how to recover from an invalid input in [this Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50403158/3422102) by checking and resetting the steam-state and removing the characters causing failure from `stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop where you are getting el titulo, el autor, y el anio, you are overwriting the 't', 'au', and 'a' variables each time through the loop.  You need to make those variables arrays or vectors.