# When I enter 2 integer inputs with a space it jumps to the second cin function

Tags: c++, user-input, cin

So when I try to input the required inputs for program I want user to enter them one by one. And when I enter the both of them at once with a space between them like:

```
5 10
```

It directly goes to the second `cin`'s end.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int asd1, asd2;

    cout << "Enter the first one: ";
    cin >> asd1;
    cout << endl;
    if (asd1 == 5) {
        cout << "First one is 5" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Enter the second one: ";
    cin >> asd2;
    cout << endl;
    if (asd2 == 10) {
        cout << "Second one is 10" << endl;
    }
}
```

And when I enter two inputs together it outputs with a ugly way which is why I'm asking this.

Output:

```
Enter the first one: 5 10

First one is 5
Enter the second one:         <<<< Here it doesn't cin.
Second one is 10
```

I tried using `cin.get()` but didn't really work.

Comment: Both `cin` are being run, and working as intended. If your intention is to force the user to input both numbers on two separate lines, then you will need to ignore input until a new line is seen.

Comment: That’s because what you want is `std::getline()`.

Comment: `auto get_int(istream& in) -> int { string line; getline(in, line); istringstream ss(line); int result; if (ss >> result) return result; throw "nope"; }`

Comment: You must **validate** every input when using `std::cin`. What happens if you slip and hit `'r'` instead of `'5'`? See [cin input (input is an int) when I input a letter, ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50403158/3422102) Line-oriiented input and then parsing what you need from that line (e.g. `getline()` and then `std::stringstream` or `std::stoi()` is a more forgiving way to go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first read statement: `cin >> asd1` reads `5` from the buffer, but leaves `10` in that buffer. The second read statement: `cin >> asd2` is able to immediately read `10` from the buffer without any further action being necessary.

If you wish to ignore the rest of that `5 10` input, you need to read the entire line into a string using `std::get line`, then parse the first `int` out and assign that to `asd1` and `asd2`.

For instance, you might write a function to do this. *Bear in mind this has zero error checking.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int get_int_line(std::istream &in) {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(in, line);
    std::istringstream sin(line);
    int i;
    sin >> i;
    
    return i;
}
```

At which point you could just write:

```
int asd1 = get_int_line(std::cin);
```